# How to bind object to <select> option in Blazor?

Tags: c#, html, blazor, webassembly

I have the following dropdown menu:

```
public class object {
    public other_object apple {get; set;}
    ...
    public string stuff {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class other_object {
    public string id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}

<select class="custom-select" @bind="@object.apple">
     <option value="@object.apple">@object.apple.name</option>
     ...
</select>
```

I want to bind the select to an object, but only want to display some attribute of that object. This will give me the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'other_object' does not
>   have an 
>       associated TypeConverter that supports conversion from a string. Apply 
>       'TypeConverterAttribute' to the type to register a converter.

Is this possible to do? I'm not really sure how the type converter thing works.

Comment: Could you share some more code? It's impossible to tell the types this way..

Comment: They are both custom objects. The other_object has two strings inside. See the code I just posted.

Comment: The types are still missing

Comment: The types for what? The name and id inside the other_object are strings, the object is a collection of objects and other information that isn't really needed here.

Comment: in the object class, either the type or name is still missing.. of the first property

Comment: Check.. But this still needs more code.. How are you initializing stuff? The code right now could not possibly work.

Comment: What more do you need? I'm just trying to figure out how to use the type converter so that I can bind my object. I don't think I need to give more code for that...

Comment: Because with the code you now have a type converter is not going to help. How does @object gets initialized?

Answer (score 7):

You cannot bind to `other_object` you can bind to a string property of `other_object` or use a [`TypeConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute?view=netstandard-2.1) to convert your `other_object` to a string.

Your code can be :

```html
<select class="custom-select" @bind="@_selected.id">
     <option value="@object.apple.id">@object.apple.name</option>
     ...
</select>
@code {
    private other_object _selected = new other_object();
    ...
}
```

Comment: How do you use TypeConverter?

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest I added the link to the `TypeConverterAttribute` doc

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this in case for any reason you need the object to be created here:

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="@object.apple.id" @onchange="@((args) => @object.apple = new other_object { id = (int)args.Value })" class="form-control">
      <option value="@object.apple.id">@object.apple.name</option>                        
</InputSelect>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution for binding an object to the `<select>` option in Blazor using `@bind-Value:get` and `@bind-Value:set`. In this example, we use `<InputSelect>` to bind the selected value to a `selected` property and define a `SetSelected` method to update the `object` object with the selected object from the `ListOtherObjects` list.

```cs
<InputSelect @bind-Value:get="selected" @bind-Value:set="SetSelected" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select an option</option>
    @foreach (var value in ListOtherObjects)
    {
        <option value="@value.Id">@value.name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>

@code {
    private string selected = null!;
    private List<other_object> ListOtherObjects = new() { new() { id = 1, name = "name1" }, new() { id = 2, name = "name2" } };
    public object object { get; set; } = new();

    void SetSelected(string value)
    {
        var _ = ListOtherObjects.Find(e => e.Id == value);
        if (_ != null)
            object.apple = _;
        selected = value;
    }
}
```

I hope this solution helps you. If you have any questions or need more information, please let me know.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. .NET 7+ introducing `@bind:get` and `@bind:set` simplifies a lot of these things.